# Should edit approvals from trusted users be binding?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I think that approvals of suggested edits by users who have enough reputation to make their own edits without requiring an approval should count as binding.

Sometimes a post from a new user would contain simple formatting errors that make reading of the question extremely hard. Such errors are often fixed within seconds. Unfortunately, when the user who edits the post does not have enough reputation, the edit gets stuck in the "needs approval" state, which keeps users with editing privileges from making additional edits, even when they approve the edit suggested earlier.

I think that making high-rep approvals binding would address this problem.

Comment: Don't approve. Click improve, that makes it binding. E.g I was the only reviewer for this [suggested edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5598199)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every single user that can approve/reject suggested edits has the rep to apply edits themselves without suggesting an edit.  This is *by definition*, you gain the ability to review edits when you have the ability to make them yourself.

People are bad at reviewing edits.  Very, very bad.  That's the whole reason we need to many votes in the first place; most users just don't do a good job, despite being able to *make* good edits themselves.

Then of course, you *can* make an additional edit to a post with a pending suggested edit without waiting for it to be approve/rejected.  Just click `Improve`.

Comment: Improve?.. I never saw that button! I'll look for it the next time this happens to me. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with "Improve" is that the option goes away after you have cast an "approve" vote.  This makes the process a pain if an edit is sorely needed but there is already a proposed edit that is fine without improvement and you'd prefer to give credit for the edit if possible.

Comment: @WarrenDew If there is a sorely needed edit, then the current edit *isn't* fine without improvement.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your proposal:

- **Reputation means absolutely nothing in review**: I assure you that there are plenty of users with barely over 2k reputation who are much better reviewers than some with high reputation.
- **Accidents happen**: There are many proposals for an undo button in review because of a bad mouse or something else. Users with high reputation need checks and balances too.
- **Users can game the system**: Imagine that two users know each other or are the same person: a user with high reputation and a user with low reputation trying to earn it.

Comment: These sound more like problems with allowing suggested edits to me…

Comment: @Cody True, but these problems would probably be more prevalent if the feature gets implemented.

Comment: Accidents aren't a real issue in this case since a mistaken approval can be fixed with an edit.